Numbers appearing twice in the same col and row in a sudoku board program
This code is giving me a headache, to summarise the goal of my program is to generate complete sudoku boards that can be used in future for a game. I'm almost there I've got no repeating numbers in the smaller grids but I am still getting repeating numbers in the larger grid.
Screenshot of my program displaying my issue:

A preface to my code:

gameGrid is a 2d array of 9 arrays considing of 9 indexes each
btnGrid is a mirror of gameGrid but is for the buttons in gui
gridXX refers to each smaller 3x3 grid on the sudoku board

The rest of the code is explained programatically within the function, I believe the problem is within the "checkCol" and "checkRow" parts which are marked with comments.
Any help at all is greatly appreciated and thank you to any commenters in advance.
private void generateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Random r = new Random();
//Row and Col max is one less as arrays start at 0
int rowMax = 9;
int colMax = 9;

for (int i = 0; i < rowMax; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colMax; j++)
    {
        bool checking = false;
        bool foundSame = false;
        while (checking == false)
        {
            foundSame = false;
            string num = r.Next(1, 10).ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(num);
            //check row
            for (int k = 0; k < rowMax; k++) {
                if (gameGrid[i,k] == num) {  foundSame = true; break; }
                if (gameGrid[i,k] == "") { break; }
            }
            //check col
            for (int k = 0; k < colMax; k++)
            {
                if (gameGrid[k,j] == num) { foundSame = true; break; }
            }
            //check square
            if (grid00.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid00, num); }
            if (grid10.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid10, num); }
            if (grid20.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid20, num); }

            if (grid01.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid01, num); }
            if (grid11.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid11, num); }
            if (grid21.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid21, num); }

            if (grid02.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid02, num); }
            if (grid12.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid12, num); }
            if (grid22.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid22, num); }


            if (foundSame == false)
            {
                checking = true;
                gameGrid[i,j] = num;
                btnGrid[i,j].Text = num;
                
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}}


I'd start out with a valid board as input and perform some random permutations instead of doing this. With permutation I mean switching two random positions in a single cell and realign the numbers in the other cells, but I got no exact idea of how to do that. I've added the algorithm tag.

@EpicAshman, why you have if (gameGrid[i,k] == "") { break; } in checkRow?.

And why the num is a random number, I think the algorithm of sudoku board should not has random.

The check to see if the string was empty was an early stage thing I forgot to take out. I am using it generate random solutions to sudoku as one of my future planned feature is to add solving puzzles apart of the program and then a functional solution is available

The main issue is apparently not with the "checkCol" and "checkRow" parts. Instead, it's that the code does not check for foundSame still being false after the 2 for loops before it checks the appropriate smaller grid. Thus, for example, if foundSame was true due to a duplicate being found in the larger grid, but it's not found within the corresponding smaller grid, then foundSame is set to false, and thus the value is set there, even though it repeats a value in a row or column of the larger grid. This is why digits may be repeated in the larger grid, but not within any of the smaller ones (note I assume the checkIfContains function, which is not shown, works correctly).
A relatively simple and easy way to fix this is to just add a check for foundSame not being set within the if statements for each of your smaller grids. Thus, for the first one, have the line of code be something like
if (!foundSame && grid00.Contains(btnGrid[i, j])) { foundSame = checkIfContains(grid00, num); }


I haven't thought carefully about whether or not this may ever happen, but I believe a potential issue is that an infinite loop may occur. This will happen if none of the values from 1 to 9 can meet the requirements for a particular cell, i.e., each one is a duplicate in the larger grid's row or column, or within the smaller grid. To avoid this happening, one way is to have an array of 9 bool values, where each value is set to false initially just before while (checking == false). At the end of that loop, if foundSame is true, set the array value corresponding to num to true. Also, if all of the array values are true, then no value will work, so the code needs to break out of the loop by doing something like throwing an exception (although you may wish to first log this in some fashion), and then perhaps clear the board and try again.

Finally, as pointed out in Nguyen Manh Cuong's comment, your line of if (gameGrid[i,k] == "") { break; } in the code to check the rows is potentially problematic. However, since you haven't shown your initialization code, this is uncertain. If there are never any blank cells, then this line doesn't do anything. On the other hand, if there is a blank cell before one which contains a duplicate cell in the row, then the code will break out of the loop without setting foundSame to be true.
Regardless, I don't see any valid purpose in having that line there, so it should likely be deleted, or at least commented out.

Yeah the check for a blank string was something that I forgot to take  from an early version. But reading your solution makes total sense and can’t believe that was an oversight of my part lol thank you so much

@EpicAshman You're welcome. I just realized there's an another potential issue, i.e., of an infinite loop occurring. As such, I've updated my answer, in a middle section, to address that possibility. However, as I stated there, I don't offhand know if this can ever possibly happen. If you're sure that it never will, you can ignore this, although it's relatively easy to do what I suggest, just to make sure.

Here's an approach to generating a complete board.
var possibles = new List<int>[9, 9];
var board = new int[9, 9];
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        possibles[i, j] = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToList();
        board[i, j] = 0;
    }

var query =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
    from j in Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
    where possibles[i, j].Any()
    select new { i, j, };

var random = new Random();
for (var n = 0; n < 81; n++)
{
    var least = query.MinByWithTies(x => possibles[x.i, x.j].Count).OrderBy(x => random.Next()).First();

    var selected = possibles[least.i, least.j][random.Next(possibles[least.i, least.j].Count)];

    possibles[least.i, least.j] = new List<int>();
    board[least.i, least.j] = selected;

    var ii = least.i / 3 * 3;
    var jj = least.j / 3 * 3;

    for (var k = 0; k < 9; k++)
    {
        possibles[least.i, k] = possibles[least.i, k].Except(new[] { selected }).ToList();
        possibles[k, least.j] = possibles[k, least.j].Except(new[] { selected }).ToList();
        possibles[ii + k / 3, jj + k % 3] = possibles[ii + k / 3, jj + k % 3].Except(new[] { selected }).ToList();
    }
}

It starts with a grid of possibilities and the board. It finds all of the cells with the least number of options and randomly chooses one. It then fills in that cell and removes the number from all of the possibilities for the rows, columns, and block related to that cell.
It the just repeats this 81 times.
The only drama is that it does fail some of the time, but it succeeds often enough to just repeat the whole process on exception. The .First() fails on the var least line.
Here's an example output of a valid grid:

It takes less that half a second to produce a grid.

Hi there just copied the code into mine and my intelisense is not recognising the .IsEmpty() method when looking at the list any thoughts? Spitting out CS1061

@EpicAshman - It's in a library I use. I'll fix the code.
